# What does scheduleJob method of Quartz scheduler exactly do?

Tags: triggers, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I wrote a simple example using job and scheduler of Quartz.
In this example I run a trigger every two second and the job prints a messago to the console.

The class that implements Job is this:

**MyJob.java**

```
public class MyJob implements Job{

    public MyJob() {
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("My job is running");
    }
}
```

In another class I have a main method to create a trigger and schedule it with a job of the MyJob class:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group")
                .withSchedule(
                        SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInSeconds(2).repeatForever()) 
                .build();


        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

    }
```

The example works, but my problem is understand what the method "scheduleJob" of quart scheduler does. I try to open the implementation but nothing to do about the code. Can someone tell me what that method does? How job and trigger are related in that method?

Comment: I don't know quartz internals, but I guess when you are scheduling a job, you're just adding an entry in some internal quartz list. Some thread probably inspect this list periodically and if it's schedule satisfies some condition (match the time it's supposed to be running and match the job execution policy -- such as for example not allow a new job run before another one is finished) then it executes it (maybe in a new thread). That's my guess.

Comment: So I think the job is WHAT must be executed, the trigger is WHEN and the scheduler is that "main process" that chooses which triggers must be executed.